# Excel copy specific data cell from multiple workbooks to a master file

Tags: vba, excel

I have various workbooks with different employee names containing different projectnumbers and hours worked on these projects. I'm trying to get these project numbers filtered out to a master file (zmaster) containing the entire row(s) of a specific project number. I need Excel to filter through the directory (specific folder cointaining all employee hours files) for matches and copy these matches into the zmaster file. The filter is cell A1 of the master file (eg. 300000 in linked picture example). Picture 1 is the master file and picture 2 is an example of the employee hours file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKs68.png (1)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/va2Yn.png (2)

Also, it would be great if Excel would filter out duplicates (eg. week 30 with the exact same hours and employee name already in the master file is most likely duplicate and should be ignored).

I'm pretty new to Excel vba and found/adjusted the following macro's. The first one copies all data from the directory and places it into the master file. The second one filters out the projectnumber matching with cell A1. However, this requires 2 steps and when I run my first macro for the second time it will also collect data already entered into the master file. Also, my second macro places matches in the same row number as where they're placed in the employee hours file and therefore removing earlier observations in the master file placed in the same row (eg. projectnumber 100000 is placed in row 2 of the employee hours file therefore copying to row 2 in the master file, removing the indicator row of the master file).

First macro:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String

Filepath = ("C:\test\”)
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsx" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
Range("A2:L9").Copy

ActiveWorkbook.Close
erow = Blad1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Second macro:

```
Sub finddata()
Dim projectnumber As Integer
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1:H9").ClearContents
projectnumber = Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Blad1").Range("A30").End(x1Up).row

For i = 1 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = projectnumber Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 12)).Copy
        Range("A100").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial x1pasteformulasandnumberformats
        End If
Next i
Range("A1").Select
End sub
```

Hopefully everything is clear and thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a lot of things to ask in one post. it might be worth breaking this down into 2 or 3 posts. I would start with looping through folders first and once that is resolved, have another post to ask about formatting. Also, both your snapshot show the same picture

Comment: Basically I need this macro to loopthroughdirectory and only copy data matching A1 of the master file with column A of the employee file. The loop is already working. However, the filter is not added into the first macro yet and I've no idea how to add a filter like this. This is roughly the only thing I need for now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

- Open each file in directory
- check that the file name is not zmaster and that it contains xlsx
- run through each row in the current file and then combine the range for copying to master file
- copy to master file last row plus 1, which is the first empty row

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub CopyToMasterFile()

      Dim MasterWB As Workbook
      Dim MasterSht As Worksheet
      Dim MasterWBShtLstRw As Long
      Dim FolderPath As String
      Dim TempFile
      Dim CurrentWB As Workbook
      Dim CurrentWBSht As Worksheet
      Dim CurrentShtLstRw As Long
      Dim CurrentShtRowRef As Long
      Dim CopyRange As Range
      Dim ProjectNumber As String


      FolderPath = "C:\test\"
      TempFile = Dir(FolderPath)

      Dim WkBk As Workbook
      Dim WkBkIsOpen As Boolean

      'Check is zmaster is open already
      For Each WkBk In Workbooks
          If WkBk.Name = "zmaster.xlsx" Then WkBkIsOpen = True
      Next WkBk

      If WkBkIsOpen Then
          Set MasterWB = Workbooks("zmaster.xlsx")
          Set MasterSht = MasterWB.Sheets("Blad1")
      Else
          Set MasterWB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "zmaster.xlsx")
          Set MasterSht = MasterWB.Sheets("Blad1")
      End If

      ProjectNumber = MasterSht.Cells(1, 1).Value



      Do While Len(TempFile) > 0

          'Checking that the file is not the master and that it is a xlsx
          If Not TempFile = "zmaster.xlsx" And InStr(1, TempFile, "xlsx", vbTextCompare) Then

              Set CopyRange = Nothing

              'Note this is the last used Row, next empty row will be this plus 1
              With MasterSht
                  MasterWBShtLstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
              End With

              Set CurrentWB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & TempFile)
              Set CurrentWBSht = CurrentWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

              With CurrentWBSht
                  CurrentShtLstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
              End With

              For CurrentShtRowRef = 1 To CurrentShtLstRw

               If CurrentWBSht.Cells(CurrentShtRowRef, "A").Value = ProjectNumber Then

                 'This is set to copy from Column A to Column L as per the question

                 If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                   'If there is nothing in Copy range then union wont work
                   'so first row of the work sheet needs to set the initial copyrange
                    Set CopyRange = CurrentWBSht.Range("A" & CurrentShtRowRef & _
                                                  ":L" & CurrentShtRowRef)
                  Else
                    'Union is quicker to be able to copy from the sheet once
                    Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, _
                                          CurrentWBSht.Range("A" & CurrentShtRowRef & _
                                                              ":L" & CurrentShtRowRef))
                 End If  ' ending   If CopyRange Is Nothing ....
               End If ' ending  If CurrentWBSht.Cells....

              Next CurrentShtRowRef

              CopyRange.Select

              'add 1 to the master file last row to be the next open row
              CopyRange.Copy MasterSht.Cells(MasterWBShtLstRw + 1, 1)

              CurrentWB.Close savechanges:=False

          End If     'ending            If Not TempFile = "zmaster.xlsx" And ....

          TempFile = Dir

      Loop

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Dear Jean-Pierre, thanks for your response. However, when i run the macro I get the following message: "zmaster.xlsx is already opened". Then the line set masterwb = workbooks.open(folderpath & "zmaster.xlsx" is highlighted by the debugging system. Any idea what may cause this problem?

Comment: @Frits, that's because the master file is already open. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks! this works for me, great. One final thing, is it possible for excel to ignore duplicates? So, if i want to update the file a second time it ignores previously added data (thus ignoring identical observations). Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Frits, yes that is easily done by going to the Data tab and pressing Remove Duplicates. It can be done with code as well, I think post it as another question.